# Error when deploying chaincode in test network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I've just started working on fabric an am having some trouble using the command:
./network.sh deployCC
after setting up my channels. This is the terminal readout:
'''
deploying chaincode on channel 'mychannel'

Vendoring Go dependencies ...
~/desktop/HF/fabric-samples/chaincode/fabcar/go ~/desktop/HF/fabric-samples/test-network
scripts/deployCC.sh: line 24: go: command not found
~/desktop/HF/fabric-samples/test-network
Finished vendoring Go dependencies
Using organization 1
++ peer lifecycle chaincode package fabcar.tar.gz --path ../chaincode/fabcar/go/ --lang golang --label fabcar_1
++ res=1
++ set +x
Error: failed to normalize chaincode path: failed to determine module root: exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Chaincode packaging on peer0.org1 has failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

ERROR !!! Deploying chaincode failed
'''
It seems that I must have messed something up in the prereqs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing 'go' prerequisite.  See in the [test network documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/test_network.html), the prerequisites section.  You will need to [install golang](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/prereqs.html#go-programming-language).

Comment: Also make sure you aren't running the script with `sudo` it is common for people to do this which overrides your current environment.

Comment: Damn.. this was the problem!!.. Thank you so much @Lindluni

Comment: I have same problem and couldn't solve it. It takes days. Can you help how did you solve? Exactly at which command sudo should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

The Golang chaincodes can only be packaged through the CLI container. All the other language chain codes can be packaged through peer containers as well.